# Combine CSS Grid & Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

Need your help to solve this pb :)
I started to study HTML/Css and I have to get the same layout (picture attached) by combining grid and flexbox.
Could you please tell me how can I do!?
When I add css flexbox in my file I loose my css grid settings
Thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CQEB.png)

I tried to add my code without success, so here is the link of the page
http://diakiunivstra.alwaysdata.net/Homework-project/webdev-project.html

Comment: Please add your code to your question and read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

I would need more specificity on which parts need adjustment. Comparing the live website to the image, there are a few. And for different parts I'd use different css strategies to tackle them.

First of all: one element can only contain one display attritube. In this case, an element display is either grid or flex.

As a second point, as a personal practice, I don't like applying a grid or a flex to the whole page. As either `display: grid` or `display: flex` might fit better for each part of the page. I prefer to keep myself more flexible in this sense.

So, I tried to not change much on what you had already done. Initially, I removed the display setting of your container and I wrapper parts of your html in div so I could decide whether I would apply grid or flexbox.
I divided it into three: header (I used grid), main (grid as well) and footer (flex!)

Once you understand how grid and flex work, they become super easy.
For grid, you have a hierarchy: a wrapper that has most of the configurations of the grid and its sons/elements below it. Generally, more divs

```
<header>
    <!-- this is where I set the grid -->
    <div class="header-wrapper"> 
        <!-- first of two sons/elements below div -->
        <div>
            <h1 class="text">End-of-study-internship</h1>
            <h2 class="text">Subject of the internship</h2>
        </div>
        <!-- end of first son -->
        <!-- second of two sons/elements below div -->
        <div>
            <img class="image" src="http://diakiunivstra.alwaysdata.net/images/logo-univstra.png"
                alt="logo-univstra" width="400" height="175">
        </div>
        <!-- end of second son -->
    </div>
    <!-- header grid ends -->
</header>
```

css applied on top of what you had already done:

```
    .header-wrapper {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .header-wrapper .text {
        display: block;
    }
```

for your nav, I simply added `padding: 20px 0;`
I used the same strategy on the main content.
(I am copying the whole code at the end)

For the footer, it seems like `display: flex` would be a better fit, as you dont have to 'fix' the content, they can just be spread throughout space.

```
<footer>
    <div class="footer-wrapper">
        <p>
            <a href="http://www.unistra.fr/index.php?id=accueil&utm_source=unistra_fr&utm_medium=unistra_fr_homepage"
                target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: cornsilk;">Université de Strasbourg</a>
        </p>
        <p>Full name</p>
        <p>Graduation</p>

    </div>
</footer>
```

the, its css (added on top of what you already had):

```
    footer{
        display: block;
    }
    .footer-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .footer-wrapper p,
    .footer-wrapper a {
        display: inline;
    }
```

Since I added some code on top of yours, I'd check what is being cancelled out once you put it all together.
Besides cancelling your display settings on your container, all my css additions are on the bottom of the style tag.
I also wrapped some html elements around divs

```
<style>
    .container {
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        font-size: 13pt;
        border: 1px solid #df4585;
        text-align: justify;
        width: 1000px;
        margin: auto;
    }

    section {
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 500px;
        display: grid;
        grid-row: 3/4;
        grid-column: 1;
    }

    aside {
        min-width: 160px;
        max-width: 200px;
        display: grid;
        grid-row: 3/4;
        grid-column: 2/3;
    }

    header {
        max-height: 160px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #df4585;
        padding: 20px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        display: grid;
        grid-row: 1/2;
        grid-column: 1/ span 2;
    }

    .text {
        display: grid;
        grid-row: 1/2;
        grid-column: 1/2;
        display: flex;
        flex-grow: 1;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .image {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        display: grid;
        grid-row: 1/2;
        grid-column: 2/3;
    }

    nav {
        font-size: 16pt;
        max-height: 50px;
        display: grid;
        grid-row: 2/3;
        grid-column: 1/ span 2;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #df4585;
    }

    nav ul {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }

    nav li {
        display: flex;
        flex-grow: 0;
        width: 170px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 20px;
        background-color: rgb(31, 31, 141);
        color: cornsilk;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }

    footer {
        font-style: italic;
        background-color: rgb(31, 31, 141);
        color: cornsilk;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        display: grid;
        grid-row: 4/5;
        grid-column: 1/3;
        border-top: 1px solid #df4585;
    }

    table {
        table-layout: auto;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        text-align: center;
        width: 500px;
    }

    th,
    td {
        border: 1px solid rgb(155, 9, 106);
    }

    .header-wrapper {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .header-wrapper .text {
        display: block;
    }

    nav {
        padding: 20px 0;
    }

    nav ul {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .main-grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
    }

    section {
        max-width: 100%;

    }

    .main-grid div {
        border: 1px blue solid;
        padding: 10px
    }

    footer {
        display: block;
    }

    .footer-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .footer-wrapper p,
    .footer-wrapper a {
        display: inline;
    }
</style>
```

your html:

```
<body class="container">
    <header>
        <!-- this is where I set the grid -->
        <div class="header-wrapper">
            <!-- first of two sons/elements below div -->
            <div>
                <h1 class="text">End-of-study-internship</h1>
                <h2 class="text">Subject of the internship</h2>
            </div>
            <!-- end of first son -->
            <!-- second of two sons/elements below div -->
            <div>
                <img class="image" src="http://diakiunivstra.alwaysdata.net/images/logo-univstra.png"
                    alt="logo-univstra" width="400" height="175">
            </div>
            <!-- end of second son -->
        </div>
        <!-- header grid ends -->
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Compagny</li>
            <li>Projects</li>
            <li>Productions</li>
            <li>Conclusion</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="main-grid">
        <div>
            <section>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus sint consectetur nostrum, labore
                    veritatis, nisi quos id quasi,
                    saepe molestias quaerat? Rem aperiam eaque tempore.<br>
                    Illum praesentium pariatur repudiandae hic.Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Possimus sint consectetur nostrum,
                    labore veritatis, nisi quos id quasi, saepe molestias quaerat? Rem aperiam eaque tempore.
                    Illum praesentium pariatur repudiandae hic.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, dicta, quo excepturi ullam nisi
                    tempore
                    nobis sapiente, deserunt quis similique non libero commodi a?
                    A ullam minus velit quia pariatur.
                </p>
                <table>
                    <caption style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic ; font-size: 14pt;">Performance and quality
                        analysis
                        report</caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="font-weight: bold;">
                            <th>Performance</th>
                            <th>Value</th>
                            <th>Performance</th>
                            <th>Value</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Problems</td>
                            <td>13</td>
                            <td>Improvement</td>
                            <td>13</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Success</td>
                            <td>66</td>
                            <td>First Octet</td>
                            <td>1.16sec</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Start of Display</td>
                            <td>3.83sec</td>
                            <td>End of Upload</td>
                            <td>8.68sec</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Speed Index</td>
                            <td>8656msec</td>
                            <td>Total Weight</td>
                            <td>2Mb</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <p style="text-align: left;">Src. https://dareboost.com</p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, necessitatibus veritatis?
                    Similique aspernatur suscipit ipsam laboriosam incidunt adipisci assumenda sint, ex, corporis dolore
                    totam
                    vero magnam a magni quidem quo?
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Obcaecati enim omnis sed alias quo odit
                    consequuntur debitis atque explicabo impedit?
                    Ipsum deserunt amet dolorem ipsam illum magnam minus harum vitae.
                </p>

            </section>
        </div>

        <div>
            <aside>
                <h3>Events</h3>
                <p>
                    KiwiParty: The one-day web conference dedicated to web quality, design, performance and
                    accessibility.
                </p>
                &#128198; March 2020
            </aside>

        </div>
    </div>



    <footer>
        <div class="footer-wrapper">
            <p>
                <a href="http://www.unistra.fr/index.php?id=accueil&utm_source=unistra_fr&utm_medium=unistra_fr_homepage"
                    target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: cornsilk;">Université de Strasbourg</a>
            </p>
            <p>Full name</p>
            <p>Graduation</p>

        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Mateus! Thank you very much for your precious advice! I just used once <div> for the section and the aside because my teacher told us to avoid it "if possible". Here is my final layout http://diakiunivstra.alwaysdata.net/Homework-project/webdev-project.html :)